# list items , 6 items in first column

Tags: html, css

I have split my list in two columns. By design in first column has to be 6 items.  How can I set it up so that 6 items are placed in the first column and all the remaining in the other columns? Right now content splits evenly.

```css
ul {
  columns: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  height: 800px;
  li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 1.25em 0 1.25em 50px;
    font: 20px/24px "PT Root UI";
    color: #272727;
    mix-blend-mode: normal;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul className="about-company-list">
  <li>
    Успешно развивается, создаёт тысячи рабочих мест, оказывает значительное влияние на развитие экономики Казахстана.

  </li>
  <li>
    Строит жилье всех уровней комфортности.
  </li>
  <li>
    Развивает строительство за пределами Казахстана
  </li>

  <li>
    Реализует проекты повышенной сложности для международных
  </li>

  <li>
    Участвует в масштабных государственных программах в сфере строительства
  </li>
  <li>
    Участвует в масштабных государственных программах в сфере строительства
  </li>
  <li>
    Участвует в масштабных государственных программах в сфере строительства
  </li>
  <li>
    Участвует в масштабных государственных программах в сфере строительства
  </li>
  <li>
    Участвует в масштабных государственных программах в сфере строительства
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can use display:flex

Comment: Why not you use two list one with 6 `li` elements and others have the remaining one and place those lists side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way, in modern browsers, would be to use `display: grid`, with six rows and two columns; set the grid to fill the rows first (so they flow top-to-bottom in column one and then resume in the top row of column two):

```css
ul {
  /* using CSS Grid Layout: */
  display: grid;

  /* defining the number of columns and rows; here we use
     the repeat() function to create 2 columns, each column
     of one fractional unit ('fr') of the available space
     and six rows, each of one fractional unit of the available
     space: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);

  /* forcing the grid to place items automatically into the rows
     rather than the columns: */
  grid-auto-flow: rows;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1.25em 0 1.25em 50px;
  font: 20px/24px "PT Root UI";
  color: #272727;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul className="about-company-list">
  <li>
    Успешно развивается, создаёт тысячи рабочих мест, оказывает значительное влияние на развитие экономики Казахстана.

  </li>
  <li>
    Строит жилье всех уровней комфортности.
  </li>
  <li>
    Развивает строительство за пределами Казахстана
  </li>

  <li>
    Реализует проекты повышенной сложности для международных
  </li>

  <li>
    Участвует в масштабных государственных программах в сфере строительства
  </li>
  <li>
    Участвует в масштабных государственных программах в сфере строительства
  </li>
  <li>
    Участвует в масштабных государственных программах в сфере строительства
  </li>
  <li>
    Участвует в масштабных государственных программах в сфере строительства
  </li>
  <li>
    Участвует в масштабных государственных программах в сфере строительства
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`grid-auto-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).

Bibliography:

- "[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)."
- "[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)."

Comment: Classic example of an SO answer

Comment: @inputforcolor: I honestly don't know if that's a criticism or compliment; is there any feedback so I can improve the answer?

Comment: entirely meant as a compliment and upvoted too _ I was actually going to add 'respect' : )